# loop interation in R

Tags: python, r

This is my Python code, I used for loop for printing.

```
a=0
for i in range(a, 3):
print(i)

#if a= 0 , output 0,1,2
#if a= 1 , output 1,2
#if a= 2 , output 2
#if a= 3 , output NO output
#if a= 4 , output NO output
```

This is my R code:

```
for (i in (0:a) ) {
print(i) 
}

#if a =3 , output 0,1,2,3
#if a =2 , output 0,1,2,
#if a =1 , output 0,1

for(i in seq(from=0, to=a)){
print(i)
}
```

I want to get output to be the same as Python, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 0
b = 3 - 1
for (i in a:b) {
  if (a > b) break
  print(i)
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output? printing the number on a new line in the console? Do you need to use a `for` loop?

Comment: actually i have to use For loop , and b  can be anything , let me check whole scenario , i will ping you , please be in touch

Comment: if i pass a=2 , i am expecting it to return nothing , but it returns 2

Comment: @jony that's in contradiction with the original post (Python example): `#if a= 2 , output 2`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
a = 1
b = 3 - 1
for (i in a:b) {
 if (b > a)
   print(i)
 else
   break 
}
```